# Does Ubuntu 18.04 create entries in certain groups for the installer by default

Tags: sudo, groups

WHat are the groups in which when installing Ubuntu 18.04 or 16.04, the installer is made a member by default.
Is adm one such group? WHat about admin? What about sudo?
If 18.04 has separate default groups for Server and Desktop installations, please specify.

Comment: Please be specific; Ubuntu 16.04 has completed it's LTS/standard support life so is now off-topic, and with 18.04 you haven't mentioned if server, or desktop.

Comment: @guiverc I have updated the question.  Largely answered anyway.

Comment: There aren't separate groups for the server, but depending on the software you install during setup, you might get added to additional groups (`debian-tor libvirtd lxd`). That's also true for Desktop if you use preseeding to install these packages.